# Start remote program via ssh and remote Touchscreen

Tags: qt, ssh, embedded-linux

Currently I am developing a program that runs on an embedded terminal with touch screen (qt embedded with QWS). In order to facilitate the testing I wrote a little script that invokes make, transfers the files to the device via scp and finally starts the program via

`ssh root@hmi "/mnt/test -qws" &`

Everything is quite straight forward so far. The only trouble is, that the application no longer accepts input from the touchscreen. My best guess is, that ssh uses stdin from the development machine. I played around with redirecting stdin locally again but without success.

To clarify things: The program is successfully started, and appears on the touch screen. The only problem is, that it does not accept any touch input (well, that's the only input device I have).

If I log in via ssh and start the program it works fine:

`ssh root@hmi
/mnt/test -qws`

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi, does your app work with a no-touchscreen remote controller? Can you log in with another terminal and check (with "ps -aux") if the ssh command succeed and that it doesn't get hanged after command execution. Maybe -n ssh's flag can help if it's a stdin redirect. Please take a look here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

Comment: Are you using tslib? Then it can be that environment variables are not available in ssh's session. See [here](http://automon.donaloconnor.net/installing-tslib-and-calibrating-it/83/). Just add them before starting your test, i.e. make a script, that sets variables and then starts your test.

Comment: @Alberto, the -n flag does not help

Comment: @yegorich Yes, I use tslib. Unfortunately it s not a matter of the environment vars.

Answer (score 0):

From your last edit, i'm thinking your program is that your app is ran and then quit. This because ssh exec the command, but doesn't keep it "alive". 
To be sure about this idea I need a confirm from you.

(1) You should do a simple test: open 2 terminals one in which you login and constantly check process with something like "ps -aux | grep myapp" and in the other one run your ssh script.

If your program run and quit immediately you have to avoid your binary is closed after command execution. To do this I'd create a small shell script, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
nohup /home/somewhere/bin/myapp.EXE & #<--just for fun :) it's a linux binary file
#placed in /home/somewhere/bin/
#notice: nohup to avoid SIGHUP and final "&" to run it in background 
#and called (i.e.) script.sh
```

And then run it from ssh with a syntax like this:

```
ssh root@pc /home/somewhere/bin/script.sh
```

Finally check again (1) now it's still alive even after ssh session is closed.

EDIT: just a brief explaination about what's wrong (if I understood what you've done)

with your ssh command:

```
ssh login@domain "command" &
```

you'd like to run "command" in background but it doesn't, this because ssh run the command and then quit, the final & is "discarded" (if you understand what i mean).

Therefore to achive your purpose you should write down a script that runs your "command" and keep it alive(nohup+final &), and then run it from ssh.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your detailed answer. Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. The app is running and does not quit until I explicitly kill it.